# Issue with generating sources from xsd schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, schema

I'm getting the following error when generating sources for my project. I have extracted a few common types to a schema called CommonTypes.xsd and I get the following error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve.4.1: Error resolving component 'nonEmptyString'. It was detected that 'nonEmptyString' has no namespace, but components with no target namesp
ace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/C:/Workspace/CommonTypes.xsd'. If 'nonEmptyString' is
 intended to have a namespace, perhaps a prefix needs to be provided. If it is intended that 'nonEmptyString' has no namespace, then an 'import' without a "namespace" attribute should
be added to 'file:/C:/Workspace/lps-performance-calculation-service/pcs-data/src/main/resources/xsd/calc/lps/CommonTypes.xsd'.
```

The following simple type is defined in my CommonTypes.xsd schema as below:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:unit="http://www.mywebsite.com/unit"
            xmlns:types="http://www.mywebsite.com/types"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            targetNamespace="http://www.mywebsite.com//types">
    <!-- import types -->
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.mywebsite.com/unit"/>
    <!-- other common types -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:pattern value=".*[^\s].*"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
```

And line 241 which causes the error is below:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Message">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="nonEmptyString">
                <xsd:attribute type="xsd:string" name="code" use="required"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="category" use="required">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="Error"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="Info"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:attribute>
                <xsd:attribute type="xsd:string" name="component" use="required"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Do you have any idea what may cause the error? I've tried searching through StackOverflow and experimenting with the targetNamespace and xmlns, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to refer to a simple type which has

- name 'nonEmptyString'
- namespace ""

But the simple type 'nonEmptyString' is defined in this XSD, which has `targetNamespace="http://www.mywebsite.com//types"`. So you should be referring to a simple type which has

- name 'nonEmptyString'
- namespace "http://www.mywebsite.com//types"

You simply need to change this:

`<xsd:extension base="nonEmptyString">`

to this:

`<xsd:extension base="types:nonEmptyString">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your `nonEmptyString` in the corresponding namespace and make this namespace referenceable via the prefix.

To do this, add `xmlns:types="http://www.mywebsite.com/types"` to `xsd:schema` of the importing schema.

Also provide the `namespace` in `xsd:import` of the importing schema. Should be something like:

```
<xsd:import
    namespace="http://www.mywebsite.com/types"
    schemaLocation="calc/lps/CommonTypes.xsd"/>
```

Then you should be able to reference your `nonEmptyString` type as `types:nonEmptyString`.